# Display a uploaded images from a folder

Tags: php

I want to display the images which i were uploaded in a folder.But while scanning that 
particular folder it displays the name of the image ...anyone help me ..

```
<?php
    $path = "C:\wamp32\www\photos/";
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
    echo "<table>";
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle)))
    {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'Thumbs.db')
            {
                echo"<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type=CHECKBOX name=$file></td>";
                echo "<td><img src='C:\wamp32\www\photos\$file' alt='$file'></td>";
                echo"<tr/>";
            }
    }
    echo"</table>";
    closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

Comment: please help i used many ways but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to show a path where you should be adding a URL.
Assuming that www is the root directory of your site, you should make it:

```
echo "<td><img src='photos/$file' alt='$file'></td>";
```

Comment: Also take a few minutes to read and understand the differences of a path and a URL.

Comment: do you know whats the reason and also some images are displaying  like blocked

Comment: There may be files that are not images in the directory. I can never know if I don't see a list of the files, some updated code or a screenshot.

Comment: i selected it as a correct answer and i dont i have that reputation to vote up now ..but i assure you that ill do that whenever i have reputations

Comment: No problem. Just make sure to ask another question if the part being asked in this one is solved.